# PHP: htmlentities and htmlspecialchars not converting some characters

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying convert all special chars into HTML safe entities on their way into my database, but I can't seem to get PHP to handle certain characters. For example, if my string contains any of the following: `¡£¢∞§¶` It gets turned into an empty string.

So for example, the following string:

`Hello£`

Get turned into an empty string after it's POSTed and processed by the following code:

```
$workDetails["copy"] = htmlentities($workDetails["copy"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

I presume I'm doing something wrong? :(

Comment: Here the link perfectly works and produces wanted result.

Comment: The link is working fine, the result is `<p>HtmlEntities: <br />&lt;Hello&gt;&iexcl;&pound;&cent;&infin;&sect;&para;</p>` ?

Comment: Huh. My bad, so it is. FireBug was lying to me. So why's it not working in my code? :(

Comment: what php version, did you save the file as utf-8 etc...

Comment: "I'm trying convert all special chars into HTML safe entities on their way into my database" — Don't do that. Convert them on their way into an HTML document instead.

Comment: Why would you save it encoded in the database? Also: is there a specific reason you are using `htmlentities` over `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: @Quentin You mean don't strip them out on the way into the database, but rather when they're being pulled from the database and placed into the HTML?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt — Yes. Escape data for format X immediately before inserting it to format X.

Comment: @Quentin That seems somewhat like taking the long way around, converting it every single time, rather than just the once, but I'll do what you suggest.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt — It is perfectly good practise to output `£` directly into HTML. It is in ASCII so you don't even have to worry about encoding issues! Even things that aren't in ASCII are better left alone — the real UTF-8 characters use fewer bytes and are easier to read in the source than HTML entities — you just need to set the encoding of the document correctly.

Comment: @Quentin I don't know what you're referring to. I've had so many issues in the past with clients in different countries not being able to see "£". Using &pound; has always been preferable.

Comment: @Quentin Huh! I had no idea that UTF-8 had gotten rid of the need to use HTML entities (except for XML spec chars). Thanks for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt As I recall correctly there are two pound signs (£ or ₤). The second is a unicode character. But even that shouldn't be a problem as long as you set your page to utf-8 encoding. For which I don't see any reason to not do it.

Comment: :-) np We are all here to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will just be enough if you change the Encoding of your website to UTF-8 via the `header()` command:

`header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` in PHP

or

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>;` at the top of your HTML template if you use one.

but if you definitely need to convert those chars to its specific html code, you should create your own function to replace the symbols which are not covered by `htmlspecialchars()` as well.